# Configure the spec_helper file to have the default driver open an incognito window in Chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am stuck trying to figure out how to get my default driver to open Chrome with an incognito window.

`Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome` is what I currently have for my default driver.

How can I add the option that tells the driver to always open an incognito window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your own driver which configures Chrome the way you want

```
Capybara.register_driver :incognito_chrome do |app|
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  browser_options.args << '--incognito'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end
```

and then set that as your default driver

```
Capybara.default_driver = :incognito_chrome
```